# Set entire select values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know the best way to populate a select element using jQuery given a hash as seed data.

**Ex:**

```
var select_options = {
  "option1": ["item1", "item2"],
  "option2": ["item3", "item4"]
};
```

`Using different hash keys to set up the select seed data.`

Comment: So the `select` will have 4 options, right?

Comment: select values is intended to be changed dynamically using the hash keys, for example if option1 then the select values will be the array associated with that option, and so on for the rest of the option.

Comment: @a7madx7 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265445/5740382 might help you

Comment: Thank you very much, it did help me indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare key of the object or directly access value of object with key. Here are two working example.

Comparing key.

```js
var select_options = {
  "option1": ["item1", "item2"],
  "option2": ["item3", "item4"]
};

$(function() {
  var selectedOption = "option1";
  createDropdown(selectedOption);
  function createDropdown(selectedOption){
    $('select').html("");
    $.map(select_options, function(val, key) { //object
      if (key == selectedOption) {
        $.map(val, function(item, index) { //array
          $('select').append($("<option>").attr('value',index).text(item));
        });
      }
    });
  }
  
  $('div').on('click', function() {
    createDropdown($(this).attr('data-option'));
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-option="option1">click for option1</div>
<div data-option="option2">click for option2</div>
<select>
</select>
```

Accessing value with key.

```js
var select_options = {
  "option1": ["item1", "item2"],
  "option2": ["item3", "item4"]
};

$(function() {
  var selectedOption = "option1";
  createDropdown(selectedOption);
  function createDropdown(selectedOption){
    $('select').html("");
    var array = select_options[selectedOption];
        $.map(array, function(item, index) { //array
          $('select').append($("<option>").attr('value',index).text(item));
        });
  }
  
  $('div').on('click', function() {
    createDropdown($(this).attr('data-option'));
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-option="option1">click for option1</div>
<div data-option="option2">click for option2</div>
<select>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, i think this is the best approach to add such a functionality, this is more than enough for me.

Comment: @a7madx7 welcome bro, happy to help you to fix your issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this. But have to check if somebody has a better way of doing this.

```js
var select_options = {
  "option1": ["item1", "item2"],
  "option2": ["item3", "item4"]
};

$(function() {

  var selectedOption = "option1";

  $.map(select_options, function(val, key) { //object
    if (key == selectedOption) {
      $.map(val, function(item, index) { //array
        console.log(item + " " + index);
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```